# Opening a new WPF form from another WPF form

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, forms

Firstly, I have a project with a Windows Form that references another project with WPF forms. The Windows Form has an `ElementHost` which child is one of the WPF documents in the other project.

Now, on this WPF document I want to have a `Button` that upon a click can open another WPF form. Either as a new standalone WPF form, as a modal or whatever.

I cannot, on the button click event, say

```
WPFform2 WPFform2=new WPFform2();
WPFform2.Show();
```

... as many other threads on the net suggest, since the `Show()` method does not exist.

My solution does not allow some sort of call that changes the main Form´s `ElementHost`, so that is not an option for me.

All my WPF forms derives from `UserControl`:

```
public partial class WPFform1: UserControl
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The form must be derived from [`Window`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.aspx) to have the `Show()` method.

Just create a new window that contains only the form you want to show and call Show on it. Or change the control's base class to `Window` (you will have to rewrite it both in XAML and in the code behind), nothing should really change, `Window` supports most of `UserControl`'s features.